# When listing remote tags in git, what does "^{}" signify?

Tags: git, github

When I do `git ls-remote --tags` to list remote tags, I'm getting a response like this:

```
45d3d8f01f5e07a0e2728012b3d50989e5971cb2        refs/tags/v1.4.6.7
c742bfaa5d2140bbbed5bb9202b30cabcb9eb531        refs/tags/v1.4.6.7^{}
a745b6d8997803e1af823582885ab17f0dba2d8e        refs/tags/v1.4.6.8
b867af5cb9469f6cfc139d355a5e7e4fc9b55a12        refs/tags/v1.4.6.8^{}
```

What does the `^{}` signify (and should I be concerned)?

Comment: Voting to close this (even though it was the question I asked) in favor of stackoverflow.com/a/15472310/558639

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is an "annotated" tag and the commit it points to (`^` means first immediate parent, in this case). e.g. in your case `c742bfaa5d2140bbbed5bb9202b30cabcb9eb531` is the parent of `refs/tags/v1.4.6.7`.

Here's a complete example:

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest                                                    
$ git init                                                                                    
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/dev/git/reftest/.git/                                  
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ touch test                                                                                    
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ git add-commit -m "hej"                                                                     
[master (root-commit) d792079] hej                                                            
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)                                                               
 create mode 100644 test                                                                      
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ git clone --bare . /d/dev/git/reftest_bare                                                  
Cloning into bare repository 'D:/dev/git/reftest_bare'...                                     
done.                                                                                         
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ git remote add origin ../reftest_bare/                                                      
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ git fetch origin                                                                            
From ../reftest_bare                                                                          
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master                                              
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ git branch -u origin/master                                                                 
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.                         
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ git tag -a 1.0 -m "test"                                                                    
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ git push                                                                                    
Everything up-to-date                                                                         
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ git push --tags                                                                             
Enumerating objects: 1, done.                                                                 
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.                                                           
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 158 bytes | 158.00 KiB/s, done.                                  
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)                                                         
To ../reftest_bare/                                                                           
 * [new tag]         1.0 -> 1.0                                                               
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ git ls-remote --tags                                                                        
From ../reftest_bare/                                                                         
79d1f428cb16028a2f8b0e0599231eae2ba76b0b        refs/tags/1.0                                 
d7920790cb316067be54ec15e4a7d27265c08fc4        refs/tags/1.0^{}                              
                                                                                          
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)                                           
$ git show 79d1f428cb16028a2f8b0e0599231eae2ba76b0b                                           
tag 1.0                                                                                       
Tagger: Martin Kjeldsen <>                                                  
Date:   Thu Oct 8 20:28:14 2020 +0200                                                         
                                                                                          
test                                                                                          
                                                                                          
commit d7920790cb316067be54ec15e4a7d27265c08fc4 (HEAD -> master, tag: 1.0,     origin/master)     
Author: Martin Kjeldsen <>                                                  
Date:   Thu Oct 8 20:27:12 2020 +0200
```

Notice how `d7920790cb316067be54ec15e4a7d27265c08fc4` is the commit pointed to by the tag `1.0` and how it is represented in the remote tag list as per your question. And if i were to simply push a light-weight tag, `test`, it stands alone in the remote tag list since it is not referenced by a real git object.

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)
$ git tag test

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)
$ git push origin test
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../reftest_bare/
 * [new tag]         test -> test

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/reftest (master)
$ git ls-remote --tags
From ../reftest_bare/
79d1f428cb16028a2f8b0e0599231eae2ba76b0b        refs/tags/1.0
d7920790cb316067be54ec15e4a7d27265c08fc4        refs/tags/1.0^{}
d7920790cb316067be54ec15e4a7d27265c08fc4        refs/tags/test
```

Comment: It's not *first parent* but rather *peeled*: `^{}` is like `^{commit}` except that if the annotated tag points to, e.g., a blob, you won't get an error.